# Make histogram graph using 3 channel using opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, exception

I tried to plot histogram of a 3 channel image and "Unhandled exception at 0x752e812f in opencv_tut.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x0019ef5c.." it keep getting this error. Cant even debug it keep getting into assembly.

The problem is in the line drawing part in the histogram others just works fine.

Here is the code:

void colorHistogram(){

```
Mat image = imread("c:/aaa.jpg");
vector<Mat> bgr_planes;
split(image, bgr_planes);

if(!image.data){

    cout<<"No image"<<endl;

}

int histSize = 256;
float range[] = {0, 256};
const float* histRange = {range};

Mat b_hist, g_hist, r_hist;

calcHist(&bgr_planes[0], 1, 0, Mat(), b_hist, 1, &histSize, &histRange, true, false);
calcHist(&bgr_planes[1], 1, 0, Mat(), g_hist, 1, &histSize, &histRange, true, false); 
calcHist(&bgr_planes[2], 1, 0, Mat(), r_hist, 1, &histSize, &histRange, true, false); 

int hist_w = 512;
int hist_h = 400;

int bin_w = cvRound((double) hist_w/histSize);

Mat histImage(hist_h, hist_w, CV_8UC3, Scalar(0,0,0));

normalize(b_hist, b_hist, 0, histImage.rows, NORM_MINMAX, -1, Mat());
normalize(g_hist, g_hist, 0, histImage.rows, NORM_MINMAX, -1, Mat());
normalize(r_hist, r_hist, 0, histImage.rows, NORM_MINMAX, -1, Mat());

for(int i=0; i<histSize; i++){

  line( histImage, Point( bin_w*(i-1), hist_h - cvRound(b_hist.at<float>(i-1))) , Point( bin_w*(i), hist_h - cvRound(b_hist.at<float>(i))), Scalar( 255, 0, 0), 2, 8, 0  );
  line( histImage, Point( bin_w*(i-1), hist_h - cvRound(g_hist.at<float>(i-1))), Point( bin_w*(i), hist_h - cvRound(g_hist.at<float>(i))), Scalar( 0, 255, 0), 2, 8, 0  );
  line( histImage, Point( bin_w*(i-1), hist_h - cvRound(r_hist.at<float>(i-1))) , Point( bin_w*(i), hist_h - cvRound(r_hist.at<float>(i))), Scalar( 0, 0, 255), 2, 8, 0  );

}

namedWindow("Histogram", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
imshow("Histogram", histImage);
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably a wayward pointer or going beyond the bounds of allocated memory. Don't assume your earlier code is right; problems like this can sometimes be caused earlier and only show up later.

In any case, it seems that you modified the code here: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/histogram_calculation/histogram_calculation.html

The main difference being that your for-loop goes from 0 to histSize and theirs goes from 1 to histSize. Since this index is used to compute array locations in the loop, I'd guess that's your problem.

Comment: ty.. i just copied this code cuz it's doing exactly what i need.  0 is the problem.